# What should I change about this diagram to power and regulate this motor to make this a working model

Tags: batteries, motor, bjt, digital-potentiometer

What if the battery was 12 V? Would this be a working model? A previous comment suggested a BJT, and to regulate the BJT with a potentiometer, but what is a BJT?

I am looking to get as small as possible components to fit in a plastic case.

I would also like to know if there are any other components I would need to run the mini digital voltmeter.

I am trying to make a regulated battery with an on/off switch to run a tiny motor.

[image]

Comment: BJT is Bipolar Junction Transistor - an NPN or PNP transitor.  If this motor has a 2.5 Amp starting current, I wouldn't consider it "tiny".

Comment: Your schematic is wrong. The motor always gets 18-20V, it's only the current limited by the **fixed** 50Ω resistance in its path. You had to connect the wiper to the motor to make it a variable resistance, giving you an adjustable voltage.

But that is rubbish, too, as then most of the energy would be simply turned into heat in the potentiometer regardless whether the motor is running or not.

What do you want to achieve? A regulated battery - not. You want this motor to drive something. What?

Comment: I'm looking to run the motor but be able to adjust the speed, so basically yes I am looking to wire up a battery that I can regulate. As well as turn on and off. In your opinion what would be the best way to wire it up so that motor would run effectively, and also keep its load up. I can happily use a 12v battery as the max I would run the motor at is about 10-10.5 v

Comment: I also don't want it to overheat... but I'm not sure what components would be best then... I am trying to make this unit quite compact.

Comment: http://www.ebay.com/itm/DC6-30V-12V-24V-8A-Motor-PWM-Speed-Controller-With-Digital-Display-Switch-LJ-/162272195287?hash=item25c82d32d7:g:-aUAAOSwCqVXiMe4

Comment: When you move the wiper of your potentiometer towards the fuse you will short-circuit the battery. You have just built a fuse destroyer.

Comment: Use an off-the shelf PWM controller like this :https://robu.in/product/dc-motor-pwm-speed-regulator-1-8v-3v-5v-6v-12v-2a-speed-control-switch-function/   They're dirct cheap and quite small and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the battery to 12 volts and connect the wiper arm of the potentiometer to the side of the potentiometer that is connected to the motor, it can be used to adjust the motor speed. The motor speed will change if the load torque changes, but that may be acceptable. The potentiometer needs to be rated for at least 5 watts or at least 0.3 amps. If you don't reduce the battery voltage, the 50 ohms rheostat in series will burn up close to half the power and provide a speed range from a little below the motor's maximum rated speed to more than 50% above maximum speed. A 5-watt potentiometer would run quite warm with a 12 volt battery and too hot with 18 to 20 volts.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response! What would you recommend would be a more efficient setup if what I would like to achieve is simply to power the motor hopefully maintaining the load while running as adequately as possible) and using a 12 volt battery? This bjt device would that be a better route? Someone suggested a dc-dc converter, but again I wouldn't know the values with which to start a test... I'm simply looking to regulate the power between 6 v up to 11-12 volts, with the average power usually being 10-10.5 volts...also looking to turn it on and off and

Comment: A simple transistor circuit would be a little more complex and no more efficient than a variable resistor. It would shift the power loss from potentiometer to transistor. A transistor with pulse width modulation would be much more efficient but significantly more complex. DC-DC converter is simply a more general term for a PWM speed/voltage controller. If you don't know where to start, it might be best to learn from the circuit you have drawn. Add an on/off switch. Find some tutorial material about electronic circuits. This is a question and answer forum. Extended discussions are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

**What would i change about this diagram to power and regulate this motor to make this a working model**

I'd avoid using the diagram altogether.

Your weak link is the 50-ohm pot. That is simply not going to survive turn-on when the pot is set for full power. At least, not in the long run.

The problem is that all of the motor current will be drawn by the wiper, and for this motor that may be as much as 2.5 amps for 200 msec. I have not looked up the specs for the pot, but if the wiper is rated for that (or within an order of magnitude), I would be astonished. Wirewound pots are more robust than carbon track, but even so the wiper connection is fragile and easily damaged by overcurrent.

There are rotary pots which are intended for this sort of application, and they are called rheostats. They are characterized by, among other things, a large and robust wiper mechanism. They are also not cheap.

I'd recommend going to either a variable power supply instead of the battery, or a power transistor in place of the pot.